# converting curl query in jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, curl

I have a curl command for getting json data and I want to send this request from javascript program. Please anybody can tell how to convert this curl command into jquery ajax request.
**Command:**

```
curl -H "Snapdeal-Affiliate-Id:<your affiliate ID>" -H "Snapdeal-Token-Id:<your affiliate Token>" "<URL for the chosen category>" -H "Accept:application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

[cURL `-H` parameters](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) add extra headers to the request.

[jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have an option `headers`, this is a *Plain JavaScript Object* with the pair *name*/*value* for each header.

Then, your cURL request will translate in something like this:

```
$.ajax(url, {
  url: "<URL for the chosen category>"
  headers: {
    "Snapdeal-Affiliate-Id":"<your affiliate ID>",
    "Snapdeal-Token-Id":"<your affiliate Token>"
  },
  accepts: "application/json"
}).done(function (data) {
  // code to handle succesful response
}).fail(function (data) {
  // code to handle error response
});
```